# Applying multiple function callbacks to array_map at once in one line php

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

Let say I have an array coming in a `$_POST` called `users`

Then I run the following callback `real_escape_string`. But lets say I have a couple more functions I would like to run as well like `clean` and `trim`. Is it possible to do this in one line?

```
$users = array_map(array($GLOBALS['conn'], 'real_escape_string'), $_POST['users']);
```

Comment: Specific to what you are proposing, DON'T! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Please review the corresponding section of the PHP documentation for [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). Note that the function accepts one callback function and any number of arrays following it, making it impossible to place multiple callbacks into a single `array_map()` call. If you want to apply multiple functions, you will need to either use nested `array_map()` calls or pass an anonymous function. Example:

```
// Nesting.
array_map('trim', array_map('strtoupper', array('  input1  ', ' Input2')));

// Anonymous function.
array_map(function($elem) {
    return trim(strtoupper($elem));
}, array('  input1  ', ' Input2'));
```

You could also iterate over a list of callbacks like this:

```
$my_callbacks = array('trim', 'strtoupper');
array_map(function($elem) use ($my_callbacks) {
    foreach($my_callbacks as $callback) {
        $elem = $callback($elem);
    }
    return $elem;
}, array('  input1  ', ' Input2'));
```

There are plenty of ways to approach this problem. You'll need to select the one that best suits your use case.